# Creating dynamic file pointers in C++

Tags: c++, file, new-operator

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = new FILE [2];

    fp[0] = fopen ("temp.txt", "w");
    fp[1] = fopen ("temp.txt", "w");

    fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
    fputs ("My name is XXX.\n", fp[1]);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to have the ease of Qt's functions hence the Qt includes.

The errors are:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'FILE {aka _IO_FILE}' and 'FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}')
     fp[0] = fopen ("temp.txt", "w");
           ^

error: cannot convert 'FILE {aka _IO_FILE}' to 'FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}' for argument '2' to 'int fputs(const char*, FILE*)'
     fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
                                         ^
```

Please make me understand the cause of these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C standard library, `stdio.h`'s `FILE` is what's known as an "opaque type". Basically, you don't know, neither do you want to know, what `FILE` is, contains, or resolves to. This happens for portability's sake. Instead, you represent files by a pointer to a `FILE`, whatever a `FILE` is, by typing `FILE*`. If you look at the `stdio` library, you'll see that *all* functions that work with files take a `FILE*` as a parameter, and not a `FILE`. After all, you should **never** create a `FILE` object yourself!

Now, to your code...

```
FILE *fp;
```

Declare variable `fp` of type `FILE*`.

```
fp = new FILE [2];
```

Assign the address of a new array of 2 `FILE`s to `fp`. **Bad!** You should never manipulate `FILE`s yourself, but `FILE*`s. So, try this instead.

```
FILE *fp[2];
```

This will declare an array of two `FILE` pointers called `fp`. The rest of your code should work correctly with this. It happens that you don't need `new` here (that's used to allocate on the heap), and is rather wasteful. You didn't even `delete`d it! If you come from a Java background, please read the differences between constructors and `operator new` in order to get things a little clearer to yourself.

I hope this has led a light on you!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
 FILE *fp;
 fp = new FILE [2];
```

Because `fp` is a pointer type, the type of `fp[0]` is `FILE`, not `FILE*`.

If you want to declare an array of two file pointers, do so directly:

```
FILE *fp[2];
```

(this means that `fp` will act like a FILE**)

Do not `new` FILE objects. fopen() allocates that memory for you. `<stdio.h>` contains C-style declarations, so the things in it do not have constructors and in general have to be operated on as if they were C objects and not C++ objects.

Comment: I found fopen in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputs/ . That , by name is a c++ website? I assumed that to be a c++ function

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius  It is a legacy function inherited from C and works the same way that it did in C. (There are people who say that you should avoid using the old C-style headers in C++ code -- I am not one of them and think that stdio is fine -- but you need to be aware that when you are using C-style headers you need to use C-style semantics.)

Comment: Can you recommed some well known website for learning c++ file handling? thanks.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius  This is a tutorial on C++ file IO:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

But, again, I think that <stdio.h> is fine to use in a C++ program. You just need to use it in the correct way.

Comment: please see this: is the code in answer wrong? https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/102065/dynamically-creating-multiple-file-pointers  as per your explanation?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius The code in that answer seems ok - note that his `fp` is a FILE**, which the malloc() then allocates as an array of `FILE*`s. (Although personally I would not use malloc() there - it is an unnecessary complication compared to just declaring `fp` as an array of 10 `FILE*`).

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius  
Note also that the code sample at daniweb is written as if it were a `C` program, using the C headers and semantics. This is fine because it uses only the part of C that compiles correctly as C++. But when you do  this, you must be careful to remember the differences between how you allocate C types and how you allocate C++ types.